# Limit of a sequence of points inside a cone

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$.

$\forall i \in \mathbb{N} \; [ x_i \in \mathbb{R}^n \; \mbox{and} \; x_i \geq \textbf{0}] $

Assume that the sequence $Ax_1, Ax_2, ...$ converges to $p$. Show that $ \exists x \in \mathbb{R}^n, x \geq \textbf{0}$, such that $p=Ax$.

I am trying to prove this statement to prove that a cone formed by finitely many vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is closed.

Edit (additional context): I got the question while reading the proof of Farkas's Lemma here: https://people.orie.cornell.edu/dpw/orie6300/fall2008/Lectures/lec07.pdf. 
The problem statement is assumed in this proof.

Comment: what do you mean with $x_i \in R^n$ and $x_i \geq 0$ ? I think you've made a typo, I think it should be $x_k \in R^n$ with $x^i \geq 0 $ for $i = 1,2,...,n$

Comment: $x_i \geq \textbf{0}$ means each co-ordinate of the vector $x_i$ is $ \geq 0$

Comment: Can you prove this for $m=1$? The simplest interesting case is $m=1$ and $n=2$.

Comment: Yes. I could prove for $m=1, n=2$. Then I could generalize for all $n$ for $m=1$, and then for all $m$ and $n$. Thanks for the hint! I will add my proof as an answer.

Comment: On closer inspection, I realized that my generalization to the $m \geq 2$ case was spurious. I got a different approach, which is my current answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\ell$ be some linear dependence of the columns of $A$, and consider some $x_t$. Thus $A(x_t + \gamma \ell) = Ax_t$ for all $\gamma$. Choosing an appropriate $\gamma$, we can ensure that $y_t = x_t + \gamma \ell$ satisfies the following two properties: $y_t \geq 0$, and $(y_t)_i = 0$ for some $i$ in the support of $\ell$ (i.e., $\ell_i \neq 0$). Let $A'$ be $A$ with the $i$'th column removed, and let $x'_t$ be $y_t$ with the $i$'th entry removed. Then $A x_t = A' x'_t$. Continuing in this way, we find a matrix $B_t$, obtained from $A$ by removing a subset of the columns, and a vector $y_t \geq 0$, such that the columns of $B_t$ are independent, and $A x_t = B_t y_t$.

There are finitely many options for $B_t$, and so we can find an infinite subsequence $(t_s)_{s \in \mathbb{N}}$ and a matrix $B$ obtained from $A$ by removing a subset of the columns such that the columns of $B$ are independent and $B y_{t_s} \to p$.

Suppose that $B$ has $m$ rows and $n'$ columns. Since all columns of $B$ are independent, necessarily $m \geq n'$. Let $C$ be an arbitrary $n' \times n'$ submatrix of $B$ obtained by removing $m-n'$ rows, so that $C$ is invertible. Let $q$ be the corresponding restriction of $p$, so that $C y_{t_s} \to q$. Then $y_{t_s} \to C^{-1} q$, and so $C^{-1} q \geq 0$ and $B C^{-1} q = p$. Adding back zeroes to $C^{-1} q$, we obtain the vector you are looking for.

Comment: Assume $x_t = (1 \; 1 \;1)^t$ and $l = (1\; -2\; 0)^t$. Now, there cannot be a $\gamma$ such that $x_t + \gamma l  \geq \vec{0}$

Comment: Take $\gamma = 1/2$ or $\gamma = -1$. In fact, you can take anything in the range $[-1,1/2]$, though if you want to zero a coordinate, you need to take one of the endpoints.

Comment: Sorry, you are right

Answer (score 0):

Come up with a basis $b_1, b_2, ..., b_k$ for the image of $A$. Given some $y$ in the image of $A$, there are unique $w_1, w_2, ..., w_k$ such that $y = \sum\limits_{j = 1}^k w_j b_j$. So take these to be functions $y \mapsto w_j(y)$. Note that these functions are continuous.

Then we have

$\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
p &= \lim\limits_{i \to \infty} A x_i \\
&= \lim\limits_{i \to \infty} \sum\limits_{j = 1}^k w_j(A x_i) b_j \\
&= \sum\limits_{j = 1}^k \lim\limits_{i \to \infty} w_j(A x_i) b_j \\
&= \sum\limits_{j = 1}^k \lim\limits_{i \to \infty} w_j(p) b_j
\end{split}
\end{equation}$

Since $p$ can be written as a linear combination of the $b_k$, we see that $p$ is in the image of $A$. This is exactly what we sought to prove.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I understood that $p \in $ Image($A$). But why should there exist an $ x \geq \textbf{0}$ such that $p = Ax$

Answer (score 0):

**Claim 1**: Let $\{ v_1, .. v_k\}$ be a linearly independent subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $\{c_{i1}, c_{i2},\; ..,\; c_{ik}\}_{i = 1}^{\infty}$ be reals.
$$ (c_{i1}v_1 +  c_{i2}v_2 + .. + c_{ik}v_k)_{i=1}^{\infty} \; \text{converges to} \; \vec{0} \implies [\; (c_{i1})_{i=1}^{\infty}  \rightarrow \; 0 \; \text{and}\; (c_{i2})_{i=1}^{\infty}  \rightarrow \; 0 \; \text{and} \; ... \; (c_{ik})_{i=1}^{\infty}  \rightarrow \; 0 ] $$

**Proof of claim 1**:
The cases $k=1$ and $k=2$ are slightly easier. I will prove the claim for the $k=3$. For $k \geq 4$, the proof is essentially the same.

Observe that
$$ (c_{i1}v_1 +  c_{i2}v_2 + c_{i3}v_3)_{i=1}^{\infty} \;\text{converges to} \; \vec{0} \iff  ({|| c_{i1}v_1 +  c_{i2}v_2 + c_{i3}v_3 ||}^2)_{i=1}^{\infty}\; \text{converges to } 0  $$
And
$$ {|| (c_{i1}v_1 +  c_{i2}v_2) + c_{i3}v_3 ||}^2 = ( ||c_{i1}v_1 +  c_{i2}v_2|| + \frac{ \langle c_{i1}v_1 +  c_{i2}v_2, \; c_{i3}v_3 \rangle}{|| c_{i1}v_1 +  c_{i2}v_2|| * ||c_{i3}v_3||} ||c_{i3}v_3||)^2 + c_{i3}^{2} ({ 1 - (\frac{ \langle c_{i1}v_1 +  c_{i2}v_2, \; c_{i3} v_3 \rangle}{|| c_{i1}v_1 +  c_{i2}v_2|| * ||c_{i3}v_3||}) }^{2} )||v_3 ||^2  $$

Note that
$$ (a_n^2 + b_n^2)_n \rightarrow 0 \implies [\;(a_n)_n \rightarrow 0 \; \text{and} \; (b_n)_n \rightarrow 0\;]  $$

Hence,
$$ (\; c_{i3}^{2} ({1 - (\frac{ \langle c_{i1}v_1 +  c_{i2}v_2, \; c_{i3} v_3 \rangle}{|| c_{i1}v_1 +  c_{i2}v_2|| * ||c_{i3}v_3||}) }^{2} )||v_3 ||^2 \;)_i  \rightarrow 0 $$

And
$$ (\; c_{i3}^{2} ({1 - (\frac{ \langle c_{i1}v_1 +  c_{i2}v_2, \; c_{i3} v_3 \rangle}{|| c_{i1}v_1 +  c_{i2}v_2|| * ||c_{i3}v_3||}) }^{2} ) \;)_i  \rightarrow 0 $$

Now we show that there exists a $t > 0$ that depends only on $v_1,v_2,v_3$ such that $ ({1 - (\frac{ \langle c_{i1}v_1 +  c_{i2}v_2, \; c_{i3} v_3 \rangle}{|| c_{i1}v_1 +  c_{i2}v_2|| * ||c_{i3}v_3||}) }^{2} ) \geq t $

This would imply that $(c_{i3}^2)_i \rightarrow 0$, which in turn implies $(c_{i3})_i \rightarrow 0$

Let $k_1v_1 + k_2v_2$ be the projection of $v_3$ onto the subspace spanned by $\{v_1,v_2\}$

$$\begin{aligned} {|\frac{ \langle c_{i1}v_1 +  c_{i2}v_2, \; c_{i3} v_3 \rangle}{|| c_{i1}v_1 +  c_{i2}v_2|| * ||c_{i3}v_3||}| } &= |\frac{ \langle c_{i1}v_1 +  c_{i2}v_2, \; v_3 \rangle}{|| c_{i1}v_1 +  c_{i2}v_2|| * ||v_3||}| 
\\  &= |\frac{ \langle c_{i1}v_1 +  c_{i2}v_2, \; k_1v_1 + k_2v_2 \rangle}{|| c_{i1}v_1 +  c_{i2}v_2|| * ||v_3||}|
\\&=
\frac{|| k_1v_1 + k_2v_2 ||}{||v_3||}*|\langle \frac{ c_{i1}v_1 +  c_{i2}v_2 }{ ||c_{i1}v_1 +  c_{i2}v_2 || }, \; \frac{k_1v_1 + k_2v_2}{||k_1v_1 + k_2v_2||} \rangle|
\\ &\leq \frac{|| k_1v_1 + k_2v_2 ||}{||v_3||}
\\ &< 1 \end{aligned}$$

Last inequality follows since $v_3$ must have a non-zero component that lies outside $span\{v_1,v_2\}$

Define the $t$ that we wanted as $ (1 -  {(\frac{|| k_1v_1 + k_2v_2 ||}{||v_3||})}^2 ) $.

We just showed that $(c_{i3})_i \rightarrow 0$

Using the same line of arguments, we can prove that $(c_{i1})_i \rightarrow 0$ and $(c_{i2})_i \rightarrow 0$

Proof of claim 1 (for $k = 3$ case) ends
$$\tag* {$\blacksquare$}$$

Now let us see why claim 1 is useful.

Let the column vectors of $A$ be $v_1,..,v_n$. There is a linearly independent subset of $\{ v_1,..,v_n \}$ that spans $span\{ v_1,..,v_n \} = Image(A)$. Wlog, assume that $\{v_1,..,v_k\}$ is such a linearly independent set.

Hence, there exists $\{d_{i1}, d_{i2}, \; .., \; d_{ik}\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ with each $d_{ij} \geq 0 $  such that for each $i \in \mathbb{N}$ :

$$Ax_i = d_{i1}v_1 + d_{i2}v_2 + .. + d_{ik}v_k $$

We know that $Ax_1, Ax_2, ..$ converges to $p$. It can be shown that $p \in  Image(A)$ from this statement.

Let $p = b_1v_1+ b_2v_2 + .. b_kv_k$

Hence,
$$ (d_{i1}v_1 + d_{i2}v_2 + .. + d_{ik}v_k)_{i=1}^{\infty} \; \rightarrow \; b_1v_1+ b_2v_2 + .. b_kv_k  $$

This implies,
$$ ( \; (d_{i1} - b_1) v_1 + (d_{i2}- b_2) v_2 + .. + (d_{ik} - b_k)v_k \;)_{i=1}^{\infty} \; \rightarrow \; \vec{0} $$

Applying claim 1, we get
$$  (d_{i1})_{i} \rightarrow b_1 \; \text{and} \; (d_{i2})_{i} \rightarrow b_2 \; .. \; \text{and} \; (d_{ik})_{i} \rightarrow b_k  $$

Recall that $d_{ij}$'s are all $\geq 0$. Hence $b_1, .. b_k$ are $\geq 0$. Now, the proof is complete.

Comment: Why is $d_{ij} \geq 0$?

Comment: It seems that $d_{ij} \geq 0$ was an oversight. This proof works only if the column vectors of A are linearly independent